# Is there a bug report tracking the power regression in the 2.6.38 kernel?

Tags: kernel, power-management

I'm looking for an official bugtracker entry (either ubuntu, or kernel) which tracks the story of power usage regression described in:

- http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_mobile_uffda
- http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_natty_power

I couldn't find any actual links or articles about resolution of the problem. Any pointers to official sources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try looking at this link; it is the bug mentioned in Release notes for Natty, known issues:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/760131

You can help test the fix by going to this [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement).

Comment: That's exactly the one I was looking for.