# Kernel patch that solves battery issues when for ubuntu ?

Tags: 11.10, kernel, power-management, updates, battery

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTAxNDM

When will this come for ubuntu ?

I am getting tired with my 11.10 dieing at little over 50 minutes of battery when at the most extreme powersaving plan.

Comment: I am also waiting for this patch to be confirmed by Canonical. This battery/overheating issue has got to be solved

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a bug report tracking the power regression in the 2.6.38 kernel?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42349/is-there-a-bug-report-tracking-the-power-regression-in-the-2-6-38-kernel)

Comment: Excuse me if I'm missing something, but this doesn't seem like a dupe to me. The answer below seems to suggest otherwise to me.

Comment: Please don't just ask the same question again, the patch will be published as soon as enough people test it and the kernel team is confident that it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hopefully, the patch will make it into the 3.0.0-13 kernel update for 11.10. You can help testing.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement

PS: ...and if you don't want to wait, apply the relevant workarounds now. Note, some of the workarounds are only relevant for Intel GPUs.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/linux-power-regression-overheating-problem-on-thinkpad-fixed/

**Example**

To add the `pcie_aspm` option, open /etc/default/grub for editing with 
 `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

find the the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and change it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"`, save and exit.

Then run `sudo update-grub`.

You can also verify whether Active State Power Management is enabled or not with
 `dmesg | grep -i aspm`

Comment: Please could you edit your answer to include the relevant workarounds like where and how to tweak the Grub config?

Comment: Done! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: excellent answer +1 - just to say - this AU question and answer is still relevant to oneiric for intel users - http://askubuntu.com/questions/38117/battery-life-decreased-after-upgrade-to-11-04/38194#38194

Comment: I'm sorry but this patch refers to the old patch Phoronix released the new patch i915.i915_rc6=1 which they claim as a fix and not a workaround. I can verify that this patch( your answer) does not solve the heating/power bug. Could you please edit your answer with the new patch PLEASE

Answer (score 2):

A kernel update is due after the SRU tickets have tags changed from "testing-needed" to "testing-done" (after testing has actually been done.)

To find the SRU tickets try looking on this web page:
http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/pending-sru.html

For 11.10 switching from 3.0.0-12.20 to 3.0.0-13.22 requires verification of the following tickets:

```
#737388 #782389 #794642 #816484 #851697 #854399 #854468 #855239
#857297 #860868 #862583 #865171 #866021 #868628 #870127 #872711
#872811 #876701 #884847
```

Comment: Separate report for Kernel updates: http://status.qa.ubuntu.com/reports/kernel-bugs/reports/sru-report.html Also note the Ubuntu Kernel Mapping: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/info/kernel-version-map.html This list helps to determine which mainline version corresponds to the Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

This is helping many people the installation of Jupiter controls, the energy expenditure

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```