# When is a Kernel update due for 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, kernel, power-management, acpi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kernel patch that solves battery issues when for ubuntu ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78991/kernel-patch-that-solves-battery-issues-when-for-ubuntu)

Thanks to Phoronix there seems to be a fix for the power regression/overheating bug in the Linux Kernel 3.0.1 bouncing around on the Internet. However this supposed fix which I read has been patched to the Kernel in a testing phase is not newbie-friendly (if you know what I mean). So I am guessing it will be included in the kernel update for 11.10. If it will please when is it due?

Linked Question:

[Kernel patch that solves battery issues when for ubuntu ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78991/kernel-patch-that-solves-battery-issues-when-for-ubuntu)